# Restore DB to a point in time SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups, database-restore

I have a sql server 2008R2 DB with FULL recovery.
A full backup done nightly at 2am (overwriting the previous night's .bak file)
Every hour I have a Transnational backup .trn files

The last full backup was done today at 3am Sept 21.
Today I was asked to make a copy of the database to a previous time Sept 20th 12PM.

I know how to restore from an older last full backup (say Sept 20 3am) and then apply the .trn files to bring it up to a certain point in time (backup with norecovery then apply trns).

But is it possible to go backwards in time in my situation given that the only full backup I have was taken 3am Sept 21st? if not please tell me how I can change my backup strategy to be able to do it in the future if I run into this again.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing much about your organization needs

I would suggest taking a FULL Backup every night.

Differential Backup every one hour and then transaction backup every 10 to 5 mins or

whatever suits your organization needs best

and SET Expirydate for your backups for 5 to 7 days so that new backup will not overwrite the backups for so many days.

I think if you make a Backup strategy for your databases like this it will be helpful in future to go back in in time.

**One more tip**  "A LESSON learnt the hard way" DO NOT FORGET to backup (master, model, msdb)

even once a week but make sure you have some sort of plan in place to backup these database.

I hope this reply will be helpful

Regards

Mo